# Underlining search results in vim (instead of highlighting them)

Tags: vim, highlighting

Right now, all of my search results in vim are highlighted in a bright (i.e. unreadable) yellow. I was wondering if there was a way to set the highlighting for search results to underline instead of highlight. I did some searching online and it seems possible, but the vim documentation is so obfuscated that I can't make out the syntax for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to modify the highlighting for the 'Search' syntax element.  You can do that with a command like this:

:highlight Search guibg=black guifg=yellow gui=underline

That command will set the text color (i.e, foreground) of the found search words to yellow (againt black background) and will underline them.  The command above alters only the highlighting for the gui, which means in gvim.  Altering in terminal, I think would be this:

:highlight Search ctermbg=black ctermfg=yellow term=underline

Comment: This command set the bg and fg colors successfully. I presume it also set the underline flag, but it seems like my terminal can't show underline. However, bg = black and fg = yellow is much better, thanks!

Comment: @Kevin:  It may just be that I gave you the wrong info re: underline.  'cterm' stands for "color terminal" and 'term' for "normal terminal".  You're definitely using a cterm.  So you might try this for underline:
highlight Search ctermbg=black ctermfg=yellow cterm=underline

Answer (score 2):

As another answer noted, you can set the syntax highlighting of search results by targetting `Search`

```
:highlight Search guibg=guibg guifg=guifg gui=italic,underline,bold
```

Setting the `guibg` and `guifg` to themselves should undo any gross colors that may be showing. If you want the results to be more/less noticeable you can tweak the `gui` settings (`:help highlight-args` for details). If you want the bg and fg colors reversed in a theme-friendly way you can use `gui=inverse`.

Comment: To highlight just using underline and keeping rest of the color the same, your command helped. But with some corrections.

On my MacVim, `guibg` as a value was not allowed. `bg` was. So this worked:    `highlight Search guibg=bg guifg=fg gui=underline`. Thanks for the reference to the help page.