# Vim: How to change the current item highlight color when substituting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vimrc, highlighting

I have changed my Vim colours so when I do a `/search`, every match is highlighted in bright yellow. This makes matches much easier to see.

However, when I perform a substitution with the confirm flag like `:%s/find/replace/gc` all the items are highlighted in yellow, which is fine, but I can't tell which item Vim is asking me to confirm.

How can I highlight the current substitution item in another colour so I can see what needs confirming?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/86604/underlining-search-results-in-vim-instead-of-highlighting-them .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The highlight group you want is "IncSearch" even if you don't have the the 'incsearch' option enabled—it is also used for the current substitution when confirmation is enabled.

See "`:help hl-IncSearch`".

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I need to play around with colors now :)

Comment: Follow up question. Is it possible to highlight matches when going through each one with `n` and `N` when just searching normally?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't mean just enabling 'hlsearch'?  I don't think the "current" match can be highlighted different than all matches, but I haven't needed it since the cursor moves to the current match with n/N.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I've set different colours for `IncSearch` and `Search`. When I `/searchterm`, the match is highlighted in the `IncSearch` colour. When I hit enter so I can press `n` to jump to each match, all matches turn to the `Search` colour. What I want is to change the colour of each match as I jump to it. Does that make sense? :)

This is what happens now with `:%s/find/replace/gc`. Each match is highighted a different colour as I press `y` or `n`.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, there's no option to do this. I don't think it is considered necessary since the cursor is supposed to be on the current match in this context, and that should be a fairly clear indicator.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Maybe I should change my cursor colour :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Heptite, I don't know whether this option could be useful or not to experts, but it would be useful to beginners, to understand how a regexp works. Actually sometimes, when I write loooong regexps such an option would be useful.

Answer (score 7):

When inside vim you can use the command mode:
`:highlight IncSearch guibg=green ctermbg=green term=underline`

To have it always, put this into your `.vimrc`:
`highlight IncSearch guibg=green ctermbg=green term=underline`